# System.Exception: Type VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext not found

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz9bp.png)

I am using the version of 11.5.17.0 and facing the error while running the json file as follows. Please check the attcahed file aslo.

Error : System.Exception: Type VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.WorkItemMigrationContext not found.
at MigrationTools.Engine.Containers.ProcessorContainer.Configure() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\Engine\Containers\ProcessorContainer.cs:line 60
at MigrationTools.MigrationEngine.Run() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\MigrationEngine.cs:line 85
at MigrationTools.ExecuteHostedService.b__6_1() in D:\a\1\s\src\MigrationTools\ExecuteHostedService.cs:line 45
[17:05:56 INF] Application is shutting down...
[17:05:56 INF] Application Ending
[17:05:56 INF] The application ran in 00:00:01.9911715 and finished at 10/09/2020 17:05:56

Comment: Please update to v11.6.1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using an outdated configuration.json format.

> Changed config design to have only the Name and not FullName of the
> class. Remove MigrationTools.Core.Configuration.FieldMap. and
> MigrationTools.Core.Configuration.Processing. from the config leaving
> only the Name of the class in ObjectType field.

This was updated in v10.1 and the easiest way to get around it is to create a new empty config using `migrator.exe init` and then port your customisations into the new format.

Comment: Hello Martin, Thank you for your suggestion, As you said update it 11.6 and found the below error during run the json file. Please have a check and suggest.

Comment: Have you created a new config?